# How to receive the variable?

Tags: angular

How to receive the variable in the componente **sibling1**?

```
<parentComponent>
  <sibling1 [data]="parentData"></sibling1>
</parentComponent>
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Whats not working in the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the component **sibling1**, you will need to use `@Input`.

This will look like

```
// Other imports
import { Input } from "@angular/core";

export class sibling1 {

    @Input data; // gets set to whatever "parentData" is

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to decorate data as by `@Input` check the example here https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Answer (score -1):

With @Input() parentData: string;